# Why does JS RegEx pull multiple values (only one that matches)?

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok this is me totally trying to learn here... in my JS console, why does this happen:

```
"[test]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/)
=> ["[test]", "test"]
```

In the example above, I am just expecting `"test"`, why are there 2 results?

The reason this is tripping me up is because I'm actually trying to work with the below (same regex, with `g` modifier)

```
"type[][random][][test]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/g)
```

With the above, what I would have originally expected to get back, just knowing RegEx is this:

```
["random", "test"]
```

What I would now expect to get back, given the original question above and experimentation in the console, would be something like this:

```
["[random]", "random", "[test]", "test"]
```

What I'm actually getting back is this:

```
["[random]", "[test]"]
```

Can anyone explain why what's happening above is happening?

---

For more context, I'm trying to get the word in the last set of brackets (i.e., `"test"`), by finding all words in brackets, and then pulling out the last one. But because the behavior I've found is not what I expected, I essentially have to do something pretty redundant, like this:

```
"type[][random][][test]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/g).slice(-1)[0].match(/\[(\w+)\]/).slice(-1)[0]
=> "test"
```

And that doesn't feel right to me

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the [docs for `match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), specifically the return value, particularly: "Return value: array => An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no matches"

Comment: And further... *"If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. __Captured groups are not returned.__"*

Comment: GREAT, thanks that was perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says, it will return the following:

> An Array containing the entire match result and any
>   parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no matches

Which explains why you get this:

```
"[test]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/)
=> ["[test]", "test"]
```

As your regex was matching whatever is inside the brackets(`[]`), it matched `[test]` and `test` was inside the parentheses.

But if you put the global flag and try again:

```
"[test]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/g)
=> ["[test]"]
```

The global flag will make it only return matches not the parentheses-captured results. To understand you can look at the following:

```
"[test][test2]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/)
=> ["[test]", "test"]

"[test][test2]".match(/\[(\w+)\]/g)
=> ["[test]", "[test2]"]
```